# mir_eval library returns inf SIR

Tags: python, signal-processing

I'm using mir_eval( https://craffel.github.io/mir_eval/ ) for evaluating some voices in terms of SDR, SIR, and SAR but only the SDR part is working and for any kind of input the output is inf for SIR and SAR has the same value as SDR. By the way, I'm working on speaker source separation and the interference of estimated sources could not be zero to expect an inf SIR.

Comment: the function that I use is this: mir_eval.separation.bss_eval_sources(reference_sources, estimated_sources, compute_permutation=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you only give the function one reference signal and one reference source and one estimation source. You need to give at least two of each stacked into a matrix, so that it can calculate the proper measurements.